# How to pass the data from HTTP GET API to mat dialog component in angular

Tags: angular, angular8

All, I am trying to get the data from API and pass the data to matdialog component and inject that MD data in mat component and display on html. But since i am trying it outside of the subscribe it is failing. Can you guys please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Main. component.ts

```
cellClicked(serv : string): void  {

  let object = this.http.get('https://XXX.execute-.amazonaws.com/PRD/ippopup?Appip=' + serv).subscribe(data => data);
  console.log(this.object)
  this.dialog.open(AppipPopupComponent,{
    width: '320px',
    height: '200px',
    panelClass: 'my-centered-dialog',
    data:{data :object}

  });
```

Mat component.ts

```
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AppipPopupComponent>,@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('test')
    this.data.subscribe(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
  }
```

Comment: Move `this.dialog.open(AppipPopupComponent,{
    width: '320px',
    height: '200px',
    panelClass: 'my-centered-dialog',
    data:{data :object}

  });` to inside the subscription block as the GET call is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this on http response you will get data in response pass it to dailog.

```
cellClicked(serv : string): void  {
      let object = this.http.get('https://XXX.execute-.amazonaws.com/PRD/ippopup?Appip=' + serv).subscribe((response:any)=> {
        this.dialog.open(AppipPopupComponent,{
        width: '320px',
        height: '200px',
        panelClass: 'my-centered-dialog',
        data:{data :response}
        });
      });
```